# Operator overloading, definition/header for all operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, mingw-w64

How best to split the following iterator code into a header and definition.

```
// std::iterator example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator, std::input_iterator_tag

class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
  int* p;
public:
  MyIterator(int* x) :p(x) {}
  MyIterator(const MyIterator& mit) : p(mit.p) {}
  MyIterator& operator++() {++p;return *this;}
  MyIterator operator++(int) {MyIterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  bool operator==(const MyIterator& rhs) const {return p==rhs.p;}
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs) const {return p!=rhs.p;}
  int& operator*() {return *p;}
};

int main () {
  int numbers[]={10,20,30,40,50};
  MyIterator from(numbers);
  MyIterator until(numbers+5);
  for (MyIterator it=from; it!=until; it++)
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/

How would you implement the other operators in this context?

This example also shows that you pass an array into the iterator but would this same approach be used if you wanted to be able to itterate through some property(s) or data that your class instance has?

Would you create a seperate iterator that works with your class or implement the operator methods inside the class itself?

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking about the class declaration and definition or the basic rules for operator overloading?

Comment: I assume this is only for an exercise or experimentation about either iterators or operator overloading? Because there's no need for your own iterator class for plain arrays. Simple pointers will work just fine, as will the "iterators" returned by `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Comment: @ron I have several classes each containing a series of pointers to other class instances. I want to iterate through these pointers and run a function on each one. I want to try to reuse a lot of the code so I want to know how to split the code definition/header for this example. Then do I create an iterator which can process the entire structure or create an iterator for each class.  Im planning on a lot of experimentation in code layout so this is both an exercise and a requirement of the work Im doing.

Comment: what has code reuse to do with seperation into header/source? Whether you have all this inline in a header or split into header/source wont have any impact on its reusability

Comment: It will if I can get my head round it :)

Comment: @TomShaw no, it'll only impact your compile & link times.... a header only impl must be compiled many times.  The usability of it however is still there (you'll note that std::vector for example (and much of boost) is header only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About splitting into implementation and definition I would do it like this

MyIterator.h file :

```
#IFNDEF MYITERATOR_H
#DEFINE MYITERATOR_H
#include <iterator>
class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
 private:
   int* p;
 public:
    MyIterator(int *);
    MyIterator(const MyIterator&);
    MyIterator& operator++();
    MyIterator operator++(int);
    bool operator==(const MyIterator&);
    bool operator!=(const MyIterator&);
    int& operator*();
};

#ENDIF
```

MyIterator.cpp file:

```
#include "MyIterator.h"

MyIterator::MyIterator(int * x){
    p = x;
}
MyIterator::MyIterator(const MyIterator& mit){
    p = mit.p;
}
MyIterator& MyIterator::operator++(){
    ++p;
    return *this;
}
MyIterator MyIterator::operator++(int x){
    MyIterator temp(*this);
    ++p;
    return temp;
}
bool MyIterator::operator==(const MyIterator& rhs){
    return p == rhs.p;
}
bool MyIterator::operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs){
    return p != rhs.p;
}
int& operator*(){
    return *p;
}
```

you just need to add `#include "MyIterator.h"` to your main program to be able to use it